# Is the Excel clipboard format documented?

Tags: excel, clipboard

If I copy data from Excel, how can I get full fidelity access to it.

From what I can see, there is a format called "BIFF8".

Is this documented? How is it different from the xls file format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BIFF format is document, by Microsoft no less: [MICROSOFT OFFICE EXCEL 97-2007 BINARY FILE FORMAT SPECIFICATION](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/1/501ED102-E53F-4CE0-AA6B-B0F93629DDC6/Office/Excel97-2007BinaryFileFormat(xls)Specification.pdf).

BIFF is the file format used by older versions of Excel.  .xlsx being an XML based format.